# How do I randomly replace the HREF of a specific URL? innerHTML affects lazy loading

Tags: javascript, random, href, str-replace, getelementbyid

Ok, I've been hitting my head for over a week now and I can't take it anymore.

My goal here is to **randomly** replace the HREF of a **specific URL** on any given page.

**For example:** **https://example.com/offer/free-pizza/**

There are versions of my URL that contain query string parameters, i.e. **https://example.com/offer/free-pizza/?sliceapp** that I want to ignore, that's why I explicitly use regex to call out the quotation marks for my specific URL in this line:

`str.replace(/"https:\/\/example\.com\/offer\/free-pizza\/"/g`

I'm deploying the code below using a Custom HTML tag in Google Tag Manager. Unfortunately, the links do not contain IDs, so I can't specifically call upon those, so I'm looking at everything contained **within the body of the page**, in other words, , which is the body of each page I'm working with. Everything works exactly as expected with the code below, *except* that the lazy-loaded images on the page do not appear.

```
<script>
  function myfunction(){
  var str = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace(/"https:\/\/example\.com\/offer\/free-pizza\/"/g, function() {
return ['https://example.com/somewhere-else/', 'https://example.com/offer/free-pizza/'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)] 
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
});
  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = res;
  }
</script>
```

From my troubleshooting, I know the issue has something to do with using **innerHTML** to return the entire . Something clearly doesn't work there with the images and the returned HTML. So I set off to instead just look at the individual URLs on the page, not the whole  section, so I could bypass the image issue altogether.

I must have written tens of dozens of variations at this point to try and accomplish this, but nothing seems to work.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='https://example.com/offer/']");
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = els[i];
  el = el.replace(/"https:\/\/example\.com\/offer\/free-pizza\/"/g, function() {
return ['https://example.com/somewhere-else/', 'https://example.com/offer/free-pizza/'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)] 
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
})};
</script>
```

I'm hoping that someone much smarter than me can see my obvious flaws and point me in the direction of how I can write this in a much more effective way, given the context and my goal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with replacing the whole document's `innerHTML` is, that you might remove (and replace) DOM nodes that have attached event listeners to them, which makes them void. I guess the lazy loading mechanism makes use of this.

Thus, instead of replacing the whole document's `innerHTML`, you could just iterate over the anchor tags and replace the `href` property:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll("a[href^='https://example.com/offer/']")
  .forEach(function (el) {
    el.href = el.href.replace(/https\:\/\/example\.com\/offer\//g, replaceFn);
  });

function replaceFn() {
  return [
    'https://example.com/somewhere-else/', 
    'https://example.com/offer/free-pizza/'
  ][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
}
```

Comment: I tried this, as you suggested, but it doesn't appear to function. It doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't replace any URLs. Am I missing something?

`<script>
document
  .querySelectorAll("a[href^='https://example.com/offer/']")
  .forEach(function (el) {
    el.href = el.href.replace(/"https:\/\/example\.com\/offer\/free-pizza\/"/g, function() {
return ['https://example.com/somewhere-else/', 'https://example.com/offer/free-pizza/'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)] 
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
});
  });</script>`

Comment: You're script contains a syntax error, has two return statements (technically the seconds would never get called) and the *needle* in your `replace` function has excess quotation marks. See updated answer for a version that should work.

Comment: I should have posted this a week ago. That's solved it! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Marking it as solved would be great, if that fixed your problem (;

Comment: Excellent answer, however it may also be safer (and more understandable) to use the javascript `URL` object instead of a regex… `let url = new URL('https://example.com/offer/free-pizza/?sliceapp');  console.log( url.origin + url.pathname );`

Comment: @naeramarth7 sorry! New to actually using this, I clicked the green arrow next to the solution, I assume that marks it as solved? Thanks again. I really appreciate it.